# Cannot boot into system on sda2

Tags: linux, boot, grub2

I had a dual-boot system of Ubuntu 14.04 and Linux mint 18. From grub I used to be able to choose Ubuntu, or Linux mint 18 on sda2. Recently, I deleted the Ubuntu partition, which was on sda3, but now whenever I boot my computer, grub2 doesn't know what to do and I just get the grub2 command line. I'm not sure what course of action I need to take to boot into Linux Mint, which has all my files.

If any more information about something is needed, I can probably provide it.

Thanks

Comment: What is the output of `ls` and `set` from the grub rescue?

Answer (score 1):

You can boot your system from grub2 rescue Then reinstall it :

First run the command `set`, it will give some information about the tow first command ( boot + root) to run from the grub rescue :

```
set prefix=(hd0,1)/boot/grub
set root=(hd0,3)
insmod normal
normal
```

If you cannot boot from the grub rescue , boot from a linux live CD/USB and reinstall grub on your hdd following this [tuto](http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-repair-restore-reinstall-grub-2-with-a-ubuntu-live-cd)

Comment: Thank you! I was aware of the set command, but not of insmod. I'm able to boot by set prefix=(hd0,2)/boot/grub and then insmod normal and normal

Comment: Use this tuto http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-repair-restore-reinstall-grub-2-with-a-ubuntu-live-cd to restore grub , if you have a separate `/boot` partition `mount` it also .